# Error when doing basic tasks in SharePoint Central Admin (2010) After moving VM

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, central-administration, administration

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space.

This error occurs when trying to provision a new web application among other things. The ULS logs don't give any other clue. (SharePoint 2010)

Comment: Could you please add more details, how you move the site to VM? is it Farm move or just CA?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the network guys didn't update the DNS records.

Thanks.